# reinit function after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to rewrite some script. This script takes some data from data attributes and rebuild block with them. All was alright, but I need to do it via AJAX. Here my modified script:

```
(function($){
jQuery.fn.someItem = function()
{
    var make = function() {
        var _$this = $(this);
        var $thumb = _$this.find('.thumb');

        function init()
        {
            $thumb.on('click', function()
            {
                if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) setNewActiveItem($(this));
                return false;
            });
        }

        function setNewActiveItem($newItem)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax-item?id=' + $newItem.data('id'),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(response)
                {
                    _$this.replaceWith(response);
                    **init();**
                }
            });
        }
        init();
    };

    return this.each(make);
};
})(jQuery);
```

All working fine, but after Ajax call and block replaced, I can't apply ajax-call in modified block again. I guess that I need to reinit "init()" function after "replaceWith()", but how to do it? Thank you for help.

Comment: I needed to reinit all function, not only init. So, sollution for me was:

$(mainDiv).find("[data-product_id='" + $newItem.data('id') + "']").someItem ();

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a delegated event handler in the `init()` when attaching your click event to the `.thumb` elements. Try this:

```
var make = function() {
    var _$this = $(this);

    function init() {
        _$this.on('click', '.thumb', function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) 
                setNewActiveItem($(this));
            return false;
        });
    }

    function setNewActiveItem($newItem) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax-item?id=' + $newItem.data('id'),
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                _$this.replaceWith(response);
            }
        });
    }
    init();
};
```

This works by assigning the click handler to the parent element and inspecting the click event as it bubbles up the DOM. It means that you can append any `.thumb` element at any time and not have to re-assign any new click handlers as the one defined on the parent will catch all.